# software architecture - how should a plugin get information from caller (c++?)

Tags: c++, plugins, architecture, software-design

say that we have some process and it uses a plugin to do an unknown implementation  -
so the plugin implements an header and called with  virtual functions to do some  work.

now what if the plugin wants data back from the main process? get some gui stuff or other changed states of objects that cannot given at  the time the virtual function  was called ?

easiest thing to do is to make the interface bi -directional so plugin can ask questions
but it feels wrong to me.

i  have read that interfaces should be one directional and actually i should have input and output interface for the plugin , but is still not answering the basic question of how to get data from the caller?

```
class A
{
 ...
 void doWork()
 {
     plugin->doWorkInPlugin();
 }
 private:
 MYinterafce* plugin;
}

class MYinterface 
{
virtual doWorkInPlugin();
...
}

class MYPlugin : public MYinterface
{
   doWorkInPlugin();
   {
       **** i want to know something in class A or GUI status or class Z *** 
    output->hello("blah");

   }
private:
MYoutputInterface *output;
}
```

update *** clarify why i use empty parameter in the function ***
the thing is doWorkInPlugin is long running function ,mayby in thread  needs to know changed states of objects that changed after the call has been made

Comment: The host program could pass a structure with information to the plugin in its initialization or on-load routine? Or pass along a pointer to an interface-class that can be used by the plugin to call functions in the host program, for example to query for certain information?

Comment: pass whatever is needed to do the work as parameter to `doWorkInPlugin();`

Comment: doWorkInPlugin needs to know changed states of objects that changed after the call has been done

Comment: @user3717741 Like SomeProgrammerDude said - define a second interface that the host program implements methods for, and then pass that interface to the plugin, such as during initialization. That will let the plugin call into the host program when it needs to ask for more info then it is given.

Comment: btw even if you want to have interface uni directional that does not prevent you to define a second interface that lets the plugin call methods of its caller

Comment: i understand that i need second "reverse" interface for the caller,
but isn't it opposed to the flow of data direction uncle bob is talking about in clean architecture book ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnDJo.png